# Two-sided ideals of $B(H)$ are hereditary

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, operator-ideals

I seem to recall that (not necessarily closed) two-sided ideals of $B(H)$ are hereditary. Is that true?

If it is, can anyone post a proof/reference?

Comment: No problem. The closing/deleting brigade has been out of control for a long time now. MSE is barely palatable to me just because I stay within my not-popular tags so we escape detection fairly often. It's sad all the content, all the good answers these people have destroyed because the asked "didn't provide context".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, this is true and it's actually due to Calkin himself. See Theorem 1.6 in

> J. W. Calkin, [Two-Sided Ideals and Congruences in the Ring of Bounded Operators in Hilbert Space](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968771?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), *Annals of Mathematics* Second Series, **42**, No. 4 (Oct., 1941), 839-873.

Calkin proved that ideals of $B(H)$ are in one-to-one correspondence with certain subsets of $c_0$ that he termed *ideals sets*. Now Theorem 1.6 tells you that the spectral set of a two-sided ideal is an ideal set which, by definition, is hereditary.

It is maybe worthwhile to add that this is not true for ideals of $K(H)$, however I don't have a counter-example off the top of my head.

Comment: Hi @Tomek, in case you ever come across the counter example in $K(H)$ you mentioned above, would you mind posting it here?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it is in order to add that the same holds for arbitrary von Neumann algebras. Indeed, let $I \lhd M$ be a two-sided ideal in a von Neumann algebra $M$. We want to show that $0\leqslant x \leqslant y \in I$ implies that $x \in I$. It follows that $\sqrt{x} = a \sqrt{y}$, where $a \in M$ is a contraction that vanishes on $(Ran(\sqrt{y}))^{\perp}$ (this is the generalised polar decomposition); the fact that $a$ can be taken to be an element of $M$ follows from the bicommutant theorem. Now, using self-adjointness of $\sqrt{x}$, we can write $x = a \sqrt{y} (\sqrt{y} a^{*}) = aya^{*} \in I$.